# Slow debugging using PyDev in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I would appreciate it very much if you helped me with the following most annoying problem:
I'm using PyDev in Eclipse on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, and every time I run my code in debug mode, it takes around 3-4 minutes to start. 
My research yielded, that it takes a very long time to run each "import" statement row (without import statements, the problem vanishes).
Can anyone tell how can I overcome this problem?

Thanks!

I'm attaching:
1) my import statements.
2) my file tree (the file I'm running is in the folder "Gil").
3) and the debug window (during these 3-4 minutes, eclipse adds more and more lines there, that just say "light.py" (this is the file I'm running))

[image: project explorer]

[image: debug window]

[image: import statements]

Comment: a hint from this thread is to disable the `variable` view : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893553/why-is-debugging-in-eclipse-pydev-so-slow-for-my-python-program

Comment: An interesting direction, but didn't help in my case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only guessing here, but from your output in PyDev it seems you're executing something with multiprocessing or another thing which creates python subprocesses (which is why I think you're having a new light.py entry every time in the debugger).

Without looking at your code it's a bit hard guessing on what's actually happening, but I can give you some suggestions here:

- Make your imports lazier (if you're always executing a new process which has to re-execute all the imports, that can indeed lead to quite more time -- imports in Python are usually slow, even more so with a debugger in place... maybe do a profile in regular mode to actually know what's going on -- if it's open source or you can afford the price, http://www.pyvmmonitor.com/ can probably help you quite a bit here -- if you haven't profiled your code before, you probably have low-hanging fruits which can give you a nice speedup).
- Use only programatic breakpoints with the remote debugger (see: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) -- this will make your code run at regular speed until it hits the programmatic breakpoint.

If none of those help, please add more details on your code (are you using stackless, greenlets, threads, multiple processes, etc? -- also 3-4 minutes may be much or not. Without having the original time to get there, it's hard to know...).

Comment: Thanks a lot! you're insight about the multi processes indeed was the helpful one. I disabled "Automatically attach to subprocesses" in PyDev preferences in Eclipse, and problem solved.